# Flurry push - issue with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, flurry

I am not finding an easy way to integrate Flurry push with Kotlin.

I added the first parts of the auto installation. and I get red lines under key parts of the script.

Mainly `.withFlurryMessagingListener(flurryMessagingListener)`
seems it can't find **flurryMessagingListener**

```
 val flurryMessagingOptions = FlurryMarketingOptions.Builder()
            .setupMessagingWithAutoIntegration()
            .withDefaultNotificationChannelId()
            .withDefaultNotificationIconResourceId(R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .withDefaultNotificationIconAccentColor()
            .withFlurryMessagingListener(flurryMessagingListener)
            .build()
```

The other issue is I don't want to put an `.withDefaultNotificationChannelId()`. According to the how to on their website - which seem out of date. I don't need to yet it tells me I have too.

Question why could this not be as easy as iOS version - that was a lot easier to install. But if anyone has a how to install with Kotlin - since Flurry support has not gotten back to me I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your listener. E.g.,

```
import com.flurry.android.marketing.messaging.FlurryMessagingListener;

FlurryMessagingListener flurryMessagingListener = new FlurryMessagingListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNotificationReceived(FlurryMessage flurryMessage) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNotificationClicked(FlurryMessage flurryMessage) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationCancelled(FlurryMessage flurryMessage) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh(String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNonFlurryNotificationReceived(Object o) {
    }
};
```

And No, it's not required to define your own channel ID (by `withDefaultNotificationChannelId`). Flurry SDK will apply the default if no explicitly defined.